# my footer is overlapping on content body

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

My footer is overlapping my content body, it should be always stick on bottom and should not be overlap on my content body.

```
my full web page access:

http://www.acmearchitectural.com/sohail/ptpage1.html

your early reply appreciated.
```

Thanks

Comment: add padding bottom of content section

Comment: Your footer position should be change into static

Answer (score 0):

give a class to footer like following:

```
.footer{
  margin-top:20px;
}
```

or you may write

```
 <div class="clearfix"></div>
```

You should maintain a margin between body and footer.

**Alternative Code:**

```
.card1 {
    background: #FFF none repeat scroll 0% 0%;
    box-shadow: 0px 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
    margin-bottom: 30px;
    border-radius: 0px;
    padding: 0 0px;
    margin-bottom: 77px !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this style for footer.

```
 .footer {
   background: #000 none repeat scroll 0 0;
   border-top: 1px solid #eaeaea;
   bottom: 0;
   left: 0;
   position: static;
   right: 0;
   top: auto;
   clear: both;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I have given a try on your page and following solution worked for me.
Give it a try.

Basically you have to make two changes in your `.footer` class which are

```
display:inline-block;  
position: static;
```

So your class look somthing look like below.

```
.footer {
    background: #000 none repeat scroll 0 0;
    border-top: 1px solid #eaeaea;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    position: static;
    right: 0;
    display: inline-block;
}
```